# Nginx: Unable to run multiple site in single URL

Tags: nginx, server

In My application i have 3 sites - User frontend , Admin panel and Splash page .I want to run **User frontend in localhost:8080** , **Admin panel in localhost:8080/admin** and **splash in localhost:8080/splash**

To run this all i used the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;  
    root /home/ajit/git/univisior;

location / {
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/FrontEnd/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}
location /admin{
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/admin/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;

}

location /splash {
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/Splash/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;

 }

}
```

The issue with this configuration is this

1. When i am opening admin site (localhost:8080/admin) i am getting error

> VM189:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

but when i am running admin site with single site configuration it works fine , nginx config is pasted below:

```
server {

        listen 9010;
        server_name localhost;
        root /home/ajit/git/univisior/admin/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
        location / {
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;
        }
        location /static {
            alias /opt/univisor;
        }
}
```

2. With splash page i am unable to get images.splash also works fine if i am running this with single site configuration just like admin.

User front is working fine but i am facing issue with admin and splash.can anybody help me out of this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. The issue in both admin and splash page were same. The path for images and scripts files in index.html was written as

```
<img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo">
.
.
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

When running index file with single site nginx configuration (admin site configuration pasted above in question) both admin and splash works fine. But when running both of them in configuration like this

```
.
.
location / {
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/FrontEnd/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}
location /admin{
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/admin/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;

}

location /splash {
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/Splash/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
.
.
```

makes issue as `<img src="../images/logo.png" alt="logo">` will look for url localhost:8080/images/logo.png instead of localhost:8080/admin/images/logo.png same applies for scripts because of this browser is not able to get scripts/images.

Inorder to solve this i replaced **../** from  index.html to have a final index.html like this.

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
.
.
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing `/` from your alias directives:

```
location / {
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/FrontEnd/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}
location /admin{
    # alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/admin/dist/;
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/admin/dist;
    # index index.html;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    try_files $url $uri/;

}

location /splash {
    # alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/Splash/dist/;
    alias /home/ajit/git/univisior/Splash/dist;
    # index index.html;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```

Comment: I am getting "403 Forbidden" error after removing / from alias

Comment: Please post or pasteyour log files.

Comment: updated config is not working . when i am opening localhost:8080/admin and localhost:8080/splash only user front end opens.